# Can Javascript get same result as C language memcpy function

Tags: javascript, c

Can Javascript get same result as C language `memcpy` function, please see below code:

```
uint32_t value;
memcpy(&value, "00", 8);
printf('%d',val);//result is 12336
```

Can Javascript print the same result?

Comment: I don't think that C code would even compile, and even if it did it would likely crash immediately. Are you just trying to construct an integer where the low-order bits are the same as the bytes in two `'0'` characters?

Comment: Copying 8 bytes from a string of 3 bytes into a destination that only holds 4  bytes on x86...ouch.

Comment: Also, in case it wasn't clear: 12336 decimal is 0x3030 hexadecimal, and the zero character is encoded as 0x30 in ASCII and descendant encodings, including UTF-8. So the two characters in the string `"00"` would be encoded into ASCII as `30 30`, and reading `30 30 00 00` as a little-endian 32-bit integer gives you the value 0x00003030, which is decimal 12336.

Comment: The C string `"00"` is encoded as the bytes `30 30 00 ??`, where the byte `??` is undefined, and any attempt to read it, or any bytes beyond it, yields *undefined behavior*: it might do something sensible, it might crash, or it might cause some other part of your program to behave in a bizarre or unpredictable manner.

Comment: Hi Daniel Pryden, did javascript have some method can convert "00" to 0x3030 directly,Thanks

Comment: @lem82275: I don't know off the top of my head but it wouldn't be hard to write one: just take the ASCII character value of each character and combine them with bit shifts. However: JavaScript doesn't actually have an `int32` type. All numbers in JavaScript are actually IEEE-754 double-precision floats.

Comment: Hi Daniel Pryden, it works , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
function stringToBuffer(string) {
 return new Uint32Array(
  string.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))
 );
}

console.log(stringToBuffer("00"));
```

Comment: That will get you to an array of `uint8` values, not a single `uint32`.

Comment: `const stringToUint32 = string => new Uint32Array(new Uint8Array(string.padEnd(string.length + (4-string.length%4)%4, '\x00').split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))).buffer)[0];` ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the C code is not correct, as you intended it. The %d needs double quotes around it, else it gets converted to an integer value (at least with gcc on linux it does). Secondly, the C code gives undefined behavior since the ASCII string is 2 bytes wide (probably) and you are copying 8 bytes from that location. Also, you are copying 4 extra bytes to the location of `value`. This gives 6 extra bytes read and 4 extra bytes written. It probably won't give a segmentation fault, since the value is stored on the stack, but the values read from memory will be compiler (and possibly run) dependent. Also, you can't be sure what other 4 bytes you are overwriting and whether that matters later (if you had more code).